# HTML5 pushState cross browser support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, pushstate

I need to do some of that fancy stuff where the URL gets updated (not with the # technique) cross browser. From what I have read, I'm not going to be able to do it with < IE10. I really could do with support and was wondering if anyone knew of ways to provide 'hacksih' support for HTML5 pushState IE8+ (ideally IE7 too if possibly).

Any idea via js/hackish etc?

Thanks!

Comment: The hashbang hack was made for that. Something like history.js for HTML4+5 should handle that.

Comment: https://github.com/balupton/history.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) is [supported on IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange).  You'd have to manage the state yourself though.

As epascarello commented, the [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) library has already done this work for you.